# How do I migrate one Core Data model to a completely new model?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm in the process of rewriting an iOS app that uses Core Data, however the currently object model is out of date and doesn't really reflect how the current version of the app uses the model. For example, there are several entities representing things like colors that I want to simplify down to a single NSString property*.

I know that a lightweight migration isn't going to cope with this kind of thing, and I'm not sure whether I could version the current model and use a manual migration either. Would it be easier to create a completely new Core Data model and then manually migrate all of the existing items into the new model? FWIW, there are generally less than 100 items and my app doesn't use iCloud sync so migration to the new modelshould be fairly quick.

*I currently have an entity with hue, saturation and brightness, but I plan to move to a single hex code string (I'm only ever using RGB colors now).

Comment: No, you cannot create new model version for this approach. When you instantiate your NSManagedObjectModel you'll get the current version of it (in your case it will be your new model with hex color string attribute). I suggest to perfrom manual migration if you actually know how to perform it - this would be much simpler and will save much time because manual migration is obvious and easy-debuggable process while using mapping model for migration isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new model version and then use a NSEntityMigrationPolicy to convert entities from one model version to another.

Define your new data model version, fill in the mapping model and set under `Custom Policy` the NSEntityMigrationPolicy file.

There is a post [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/286529-core-data-versioning-non-trivial-value-expressions.html) that should get you started on the entity migration policy.
Their example is:

```
- (BOOL)createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:(NSManagedObject *)inSourceInstance
                                 entityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)inMapping
      manager:(NSMigrationManager *)inManager
                                         error:(NSError **)outError
{

NSManagedObject *newObject;
NSEntityDescription *sourceInstanceEntity = [inSourceInstance entity];

if ( [[sourceInstanceEntity name] isEqualToString:@"Foo"] )
{
  newObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Foo"
                                                 inManagedObjectContext:[inManager destinationContext]];


  NSDictionary *keyValDict = [inSourceInstance committedValuesForKeys:nil];
  NSArray *allKeys = [[[inSourceInstance entity] attributesByName] allKeys];
  NSInteger i, max;
  max = [allKeys count];
  for (i=0 ; i< max ; i++)
  {
  // Get key and value
  NSString *key = [allKeys objectAtIndex:i];
  id value = [keyValDict objectForKey:key];
  if ( [key isEqualToString:@"Bar"] )
  {
    [newObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:[value boolValue]] forKey:key];
  }
  else
    [newObject setValue:value forKey:key];
  }

}

[inManager associateSourceInstance:inSourceInstance
             withDestinationInstance:newObject
                     forEntityMapping:inMapping];

return YES;
}
```

Basically what you do is to go over the attributes (`keys`) in the `sourceInstance`, called "Foo" in the example. The `sourceInstance` is your current entity with hue, saturation and brightness. For each attribute perform your magic to create the "single hex code string". This string will become the value for the `key` in the `newObject`.

Towards the end of this [post](http://www.preenandprune.com/cocoamondo/?p=468) there is a `migrateIfNeeded` method to check if the conversion is needed. (not sure is you need it or if you have an isNeeded logic already in place)